# How to create a random array in a certain range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, numpy-random

Suppose I want to create a list or a numpy array of 5 elements like this:

```
array = [i, j, k, l, m]
```

where:

- `i` is in range 1.5 to 12.4
- `j` is in range 0 to 5
- `k` is in range 4 to 16
- `l` is in range 3 to 5
- `m` is in range 2.4 to 8.9.

This is an example to show that some ranges include fractions. What would be an easy way to do this?

Comment: 5-dimensional or 5 elements?

Comment: Make 5 appropriate calls to `np.random` functions and stick the results in an array.

Comment: @Divakar 5-elemental :-D

Comment: Are j, k, and l allowed to take fractional values?

Comment: @user2357112 No. Those take natural numbers only

Comment: @ClementAttlee: Are the right endpoints inclusive or exclusive? For example, can j be 5?

Comment: @user2357112 The non-fractional endpoints are exclusive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just do (thanks user2357112!)

```
[np.random.uniform(1.5, 12.4), np.random.uniform(0, 5), ...]
```

using [`numpy.random.uniform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html).

Comment: This already exists; it's [`np.random.uniform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html).

Comment: [Apparently the middle 3 elements have to be integers.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36412006/how-to-create-a-random-array-in-a-certain-range?noredirect=1#comment60440012_36412006)

Comment: This is a good answer, but it ignores the fact that some of the ranges don't include fractions.

Comment: @ClementAttlee Thanks. Not sure what "some of the ranges don't include fractions" means, though.

Comment: @AmiTavory - You can use `np.random.randint` to create integer. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36412006/how-to-create-a-random-array-in-a-certain-range#answer-36412179

Comment: @MSeifert Ah, got it. Good answer.

Comment: @AmiTavory `j`, `k`, and `l` should only produce random numbers that are natural (i.e no fractions). For the rest of the pack, it's ok for the randomly generated numbers to be fractional. Sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: @ClementAttlee Got it. I suggest you seeMSeifert's answer, then - he apparently addressed it (sorry to say, but I didn't get that from the question).

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest generating them by hand and create the list later:

```
import numpy as np
i = np.random.uniform(1.5, 12.4)
j = np.random.randint(0, 5)  # 5 not included use (0, 6) if 5 should be possible
k = np.random.randint(4, 16) # dito
l = np.random.randint(3, 5)  # dito
m = np.random.uniform(2.4, 8.9.)

array = np.array([i, j, k, l, m]) # as numpy array
# array([  3.33114735,   3.        ,  14.        ,   4.        ,   4.80649945])

array = [i, j, k, l, m]           # or as list
# [3.33114735, 3, 14, 4, 4.80649945]
```

---

If you want to create them all in one go you can use `np.random.random` use the range and the lower-bound to modify them and convert them to integer where you don't want floats:

```
# Generate 5 random numbers between 0 and 1
rand_numbers = np.random.random(5) 

# Lower limit and the range of the values:
lowerlimit = np.array([1.5, 0, 4, 3, 2.4])
dynamicrange = np.array([12.4-1.5, 5-0, 16-4, 5-3, 8.9-2.4]) # upper limit - lower limit

# Apply the range
result = rand_numbers * dynamicrange + lowerlimit

# convert second, third and forth element to integer
result[1:4] = np.floor(result[1:4]) 

print(result)
# array([ 12.32799347,   1.        ,  13.        ,   4.        ,   7.19487119])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
array = [random.uniform(1.5, 12.4), random.uniform(0,5)]

print(array)
```

prints:

```
[9.444064187694842, 1.2256912728995506]
```

You might want to round these with round()